# AJAX-Upload not calling onComplete when completed

Tags: jquery, ajax, ajax-upload

NOTICE: I have read through [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7106412/jquery-ajaxupload-plugin-doesnt-fire-oncomplete-event) which is almost the same.

I am currently uploading an image with AjaxUpload.js which works fine. The file gets uploaded BUT the `onComplete` never gets called.

The tutorial I followed was this one: http://www.zurb.com/playground/ajax_upload

My code is the same, except for what happens in the `onSubmit` & `onComplete` functions.

Here is what I use in my `$(document).ready()`

```
new AjaxUpload('imageUpload', {
    action: $('form#imageUploadForm').attr('action'),
    name: 'image',
    onSubmit: function(file, extension)
    {
        $('div.popupwindowlogo').children().hide();
        $('div.popupwindowlogo').append('<img class="popupwindowlogoimage temp" src="images/loading.gif"><div class="center temp">Uploading...</div>'); //IS LOADING indicator
    },
    onComplete: function(file, response)
    {
        alert("FINISHED");
    }
});
```

As you can guess, `"FINISHED"` never gets alerted to me.

Take note, I am not returning "false" as response to the upload.

Is there anything I could have missed?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you got reason behind this?